# Delay in starting scooter due to loose brake connection

Tags: brakes, starting, scooter

To start my 125cc Chinese scooter, I first need to hold down the right brake. While trying to do this, I almost always have to first play around with the right brake to position it in a way which will start the scooter i.e the scooter does not start by just holding down the brake.

I confirmed that the issue is with the right brake since the brake light will only turn on when I hold down the brake at a certain angle (not just normally holding down the brake).

Any ideas of how I can do tests (probably with my multimeter) to find where the problem is? I plan to open up the front part of the scooter this weekend.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the brake light needs to be on and only illuminates at certain positions, I'd suspect the switch associated with it is bad.

Comment: Aha. Are there any tests I can do to confirm this, or I should just replace the switch?

Comment: Put a multimeter on the circuit and check for continuity. If it behaves when testing like it does when you're trying to ride it, you've found the culprit. I'm talking about directly at the switch.